# ASP.NET MVC - Ajax.BeginForm renders form with the wrong Action

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have two versions of one project and there is an issue that happens in one version only.

The issue is: 
After some debugging I found out that the form generated from the Helper `Ajax.BeginForm` generates `<form>` with the wrong action.

In other word, same View and same Controller with same code (Copy-Paste) in both versions, but the output is different.

CODE IN BOTH Versions:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("GetTasks", "Company", new AjaxOptions
{
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
    UpdateTargetId = "divTasks",
    LoadingElementId = "loadding",
    LoadingElementDuration = 30
}, new { @id = "SearchForm" }))
{
    //Some HTML
}
```

Correct Output:

```
<form action="/Company/GetTasks" ... etc></form>
```

Wrong Output:

```
<form action="/Company" ... etc></form>
```

P.S: Same Web.config in both

What could be the problem?

Comment: The order of routeValues and ajaxOptions parameters is wrong.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470605%28v=vs.118%29.aspx
Also, the @ prefix in front of id should be removed.
Try fixing your code and see if the problem persists.

Comment: @Dusan I don't think that is the problem, because as I said I have same code in other version and it works fine, so I thought that the problem is in higher layer, not in code layer.

Comment: Maybe you have set the GetTasks to be default action for route, that would explain why it is missing from action attribute?
Try to output @Url.Action("GetTasks", "Company") inside problematic view and see which url you get...